# How to set name to Streamable download links with tokens at it's end?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to set name to the streamable download links with some token id's at its end. I used the HTML5 Download attribute and Content-Disposition Methods but it won't work for me. I'm using PHP codes to extract the streaming links

I used this method:

```
<a href="https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/dxsZzMQL3TdG.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNl..........warBhKbR7Lr86aDLOdkjkDSNprxVyN3ClwEgUmGMwSC6jCwN~p4Ww__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJAGZ7VMH2PFPW6UQ" download="Despacito.mp3" > Download </a>
```

It doesn't work.

Any way to download the file with required name ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what you mean by streamable, but I assume you want that the user would download a mp3 file that has a unique name on your server and once downloaded it would be given by default another name that the name of the file on your server.

This can be done by editing the headers of your file

on the html side it would look like

```
<a href="https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/download.php?file=dxsZzMQL3TdG.128.mp3&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNl..........warBhKbR7Lr86aDLOdkjkDSNprxVyN3ClwEgUmGMwSC6jCwN~p4Ww__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJAGZ7VMH2PFPW6UQ">Download</a>
```

and in your download.php file it would look like

```
<?php
if($_GET['file'] == 'dxsZzMQL3TdG.128.mp3') {
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg3');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Despacito.mp3"');
    readfile('dxsZzMQL3TdG.128.mp3');
}
```

Comment: The files are not hosted on my server, I'm just extract the file from another server and i need to name that file. Will content-disposition method works for cross region servers ? I'm new to this.

Comment: if you want to have this to work with php, you can download the file on your server then send it to the user and delete it from your server once the user has downloaded the file.

Comment: If you don't control the server where the file is, what you want to do might be possible with a javascript but that will not be a php solution

Comment: I don't have the control with the server. If it is possible with Javascript means could you provide me the Js codes for this issue

Comment: no, I don't know the js code to do this with javascript, simply the php solution above will work provided that you are willing to download the files first on your server, which you can do quite simply using the copy() function